# Unit testing using Mockito 3.x fails randomly

Tags: java, mockito

Here is the relevant code in my test:

```
private MockedStatic<MyDAO> myDAOStaticMock;

@Captor
ArgumentCaptor<SomeInput> someInputCaptor;

@Before
public void before() {
  myDAOStaticMock = Mockito.mockStatic(MyDAO.class);
}

@After
public void after() {
  myDAOStaticMock.close();
}

@Test
public void test() {
  thingImTesting.methodThatCallsDaoStatically();

  myDAOStaticMock.verify(() -> MyDao.staticMethod(someInputCaptor.capture()), times(2));
}
```

When I run this test in intellij, it almost always works. When it runs through our build system, it fails every time. The error is that there is 0 interaction with this mock.

What might be the problem with this particular verify, when all of the rest of my static checks work fine?

Edit: I was wrong about the reason for the issue and the static checks were not related. See my answer for more information.

Comment: If you compile the test on command line like your build system does (for example mvn test...), do you have the same issue than you observe in your build system?

Answer (score 0):

I was wrong about the reason these tests failed in the build system. The unit test I wrote called DateTime.now() which has a different result depending on the timezone of where you are running the code. My build system was running the code in a different timezone, so the test failed in that context.

By being explicit about time zone in my unit test (e.g. DateTime.now().withZone(whatever)), I was able to fix the issue.

Comment: How exactly was this a timezone issue? Your question does not mention anything about dates or time zones. Please edit your question and answer to include a description how changing/setting the time zone solved your problem.

Comment: Btw, I go a long way to write my unit tests in a way that all date & time values can be hardwired, i.e. the code calling DateTime.now() would never run during an unit test in my code. The philosophy is to have unit tests with no external dependencies. DateTime.now (with zone or without) is as bad as the production database, one has no control at all about it. Unit tests with external dependencies tends to be less stable in the long run.

Comment: I have had a number of issues with Java APIs which shortcuts some parameters using system defaults - things like encoding, locale or time zone. I have learnt which most of these APIs are and try to avoid them and pass the parameters explicitly. Of course, unless when I woudl be working in context where exactly that would be required, but that is not my case.